# Swift: Retrieve LocalPlayer GC Score

Tags: swift, game-center-leaderboard

Below is my code for getting localplayer's game center score.

```
if (GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated) {
    GKLeaderboard.loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler { objects, error in
        if let e = error {
            print(e)
        } else {
            let leaderboards = objects! as [GKLeaderboard]
            print(leaderboards)
            for leaderboard in leaderboards {
                print(leaderboard)
                print(leaderboard.localPlayerScore) // This prints nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get `nil` for `print(leaderboard.localPlayerScore)` ,While I know for sure that local player has score saved on this leaderboard. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got to call

```
leaderboard.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler() { scores, error in
    if error == nil {
          print(leaderboard.localPlayerScore)
    }
}
```